# How to view missing buttons even after constraints have been applied?

Tags: java, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I have been trying to connect to parse server and amazon web services to create a login database.

Currently, I have connected the server and the amazon web services. However, now when I add the buttons for the login details and after writing the associated code, the buttons does not show when the app is running even after I have applied constraints.

This file has been downloaded by a Udemy course that I am currently doing. The file is an old file and I had several errors that I had to fix with regards to gradle files, missing toolboxes etc.

in my **Logcat**, I get the following information

> 2019-07-20 22:33:21.627 15940-15940/? D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
>       2019-07-20 22:33:21.630 15940-15940/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
>       2019-07-20 22:33:21.630 15940-15940/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
>       2019-07-20 22:33:21.668 15940-15940/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.364 15940-15940/? I/m.parse.starte: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.387 15940-15940/? E/m.parse.starte: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.388 15940-15940/? W/m.parse.starte: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.516 15940-15940/com.parse.starter I/m.parse.starte: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.799 15940-15940/com.parse.starter W/m.parse.starte: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.800 15940-15940/com.parse.starter I/chatty: uid=10136(com.parse.starter) identical 10 lines
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.800 15940-15940/com.parse.starter W/m.parse.starte: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.836 15940-15940/com.parse.starter I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
>       2019-07-20 23:23:22.839 15940-15940/com.parse.starter I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.155 15940-15940/com.parse.starter W/m.parse.starte: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.155 15940-15940/com.parse.starter W/m.parse.starte: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.232 15940-17541/com.parse.starter D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.308 15940-17536/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.309 15940-17536/com.parse.starter W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.309 15940-17536/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.317 15940-17536/com.parse.starter D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.317 15940-17536/com.parse.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeb87fdc0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.335 15940-17536/com.parse.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb87fdc0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe07b4540)
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.391 15940-17536/com.parse.starter W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.418 15940-17536/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Setting buffer count to 3, min_undequeued 1, extraBuffers 0
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.442 15940-17536/com.parse.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb87fdc0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe07b4540)
>       2019-07-20 23:23:23.446 15940-17536/com.parse.starter D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0

my sdk information in the `build.gradle` file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

   // androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and my `build.gradle` for the project is:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

my `acitivity__main.xml` code is :

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
  ~ All rights reserved.
  ~
  ~ This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
  ~ LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
  ~ of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
  -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="145dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="581dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:text="SIGN UP"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_width="302dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="376dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="124dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="354dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="268dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

so I should be able to view the buttons and Editboxes that I have created but they don't show when I run the application.

This is MainActivity.java

```java
    /*
     * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
     * All rights reserved.
     *
     * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
     * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
     * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
     */
    package com.parse.starter;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Switch;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.parse.GetCallback;
    import com.parse.LogInCallback;
    import com.parse.Parse;
    import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
    import com.parse.ParseAnonymousUtils;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
    import com.parse.ParseQuery;
    import com.parse.ParseUser;
    import com.parse.SaveCallback;
    import com.parse.SignUpCallback;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      public void signUpClicked(View view){
        EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);

        if (usernameEditText.getText().toString() == "" || passwordEditText.getText().toString() == ""){
          Toast.makeText(this, "A username and password are required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else  {
          ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
          user.setUsername(usernameEditText.getText().toString());
          user.setPassword(passwordEditText.getText().toString());

          user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
              if (e==null){
                //things are good and works
                Log.i("Sign up", "scucess");
              }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            }
          });
        }

      }
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

      }

    }
```

Comment: can you post yourMainActivity.java file?

Comment: did you initialize setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ?

Comment: I added my MainAcitivty to the post, please have a look. With regards to your second point, my setContentView is at R.layout.activity_main

Comment: I suspect the problem is because of the margin, can you remove the whole margin settings and try again?

Comment: tried, the margin is not the issue.. it still has the same problem

Comment: I tried acitivity__main.xml, it is working, can you share your project?

Comment: the problem is fixed ... I have no idea how.. I just downloaded a different but similar project which had all of the settings that I wanted.. and it allowed me to make view my app properly.